# "RLException: unused args" Can't run launch file ROS

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I am working in Ubuntu[18.04] using ROS Melodic attempting to simulate the summit_xl_steel robot.

I can successfully build the packages using `catkin_make`.

Running this command: `roslaunch summit_xl_sim_bringup summit_xl_complete.launch`

The terminal output is as follows:

```
... logging to /home/developer/.ros/log/621f806e-30da-11ec-bda4-0242ac120003/roslaunch-b5f2eaf84429-23052.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
Deprecated: xacro tag 'sensor_axis_gazebo' w/o 'xacro:' xml namespace prefix (will be forbidden in Noetic)
when processing file: /workspace/src/summit_xl_common/summit_xl_description/robots/summit_xl_std.urdf.xacro
Use the following command to fix incorrect tag usage:
find . -iname "*.xacro" | xargs sed -i 's#<\([/]\?\)\(if\|unless\|include\|arg\|property\|macro\|insert_block\)#<\1xacro:\2#g'

RLException: unused args [arm_model, arm_manufacturer] for include of [/workspace/src/summit_xl_common/summit_xl_control/launch/summit_xl_control.launch]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I have used the command suggested for fix incorrect tag usage, however, this does not change anything. I have also rebuilt and re sourced the environment multiple times to ensure that that is not causing the error.

The launch file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="id_robot" default="$(optenv ROBOT_ID robot)"/>
  <arg name="prefix" default="$(arg id_robot)_"/>

  <!-- kinematics: skid, omni -->
  <arg name="kinematics" default="$(optenv ROBOT_KINEMATICS skid)"/>
  <arg name="wheel_diameter" default="$(optenv ROBOT_WHEEL_DIAMETER 0.22)"/>
  <arg name="track_width" default="$(optenv ROBOT_TRACK_WIDTH 0.439)"/>
  <arg name="wheel_base" default="$(optenv ROBOT_WHEEL_BASE 0.430)"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame" default="$(arg prefix)odom"/>
  <arg name="base_frame" default="$(arg prefix)base_footprint"/>
  <arg name="ros_planar_move_plugin" default="false"/>
  <arg name="sim" default="false"/>
  <arg name="sim_arm_control" default="false"/>
  <arg name="cmd_vel" default="robotnik_base_control/cmd_vel"/>
  <arg name="launch_pantilt_camera_controller" default="false"/>
  <arg name="odom_broadcast_tf" default="true"/>
  <!-- kinova arm -->
  <arg name="kinova_arm" default="j2s7s300"/>
  <arg name="arm_prefix" default="$(arg prefix)$(arg kinova_arm)"/>
  <arg name="is7dof" default="true"/>

  <!-- Robot - Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <group unless="$(arg sim)">
      <rosparam file="$(find summit_xl_control)/config/robot_control.yaml" command="load" subst_value="true"/>

      <!-- load the controllers -->
      <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="
          robotnik_base_control
          joint_read_state_controller
          ">
      </node>

  </group>
    <!-- Simulation - Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <group if="$(arg sim)">
      <rosparam file="$(find summit_xl_control)/config/simulation/robot_control.yaml" command="load" subst_value="true"/>

    <group if="$(arg sim_arm_control)">
      <!-- Kinova -->
      <include file="$(find summit_xl_control)/launch/kinova_control.launch">
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
        <arg name="kinova_arm" value="$(arg kinova_arm)"/>
        <arg name="arm_prefix" value="$(arg arm_prefix)"/>
        <arg name="use_trajectory_controller" value="false"/>
        <arg name="is7dof" value="$(arg is7dof)"/>
      </include>
    </group>

    <!-- if it has camera ptz -->
    <group if="$(arg launch_pantilt_camera_controller)">
      <node if="$(arg ros_planar_move_plugin)" name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="
        joint_read_state_controller
        joint_pan_position_controller
        joint_tilt_position_controller
       ">
      </node>

      <!-- load the robotnik_base_control ros controllers -->
      <node unless="$(arg ros_planar_move_plugin)" name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="
        robotnik_base_control
        joint_read_state_controller
        joint_pan_position_controller
        joint_tilt_position_controller
       ">
      </node>
    </group>
    <!-- if does not have camera ptz -->
    <group unless="$(arg launch_pantilt_camera_controller)">
      <node if="$(arg ros_planar_move_plugin)" name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="
        joint_read_state_controller
       ">
      </node>

      <!-- load the robotnik_base_control ros controllers -->
      <node unless="$(arg ros_planar_move_plugin)" name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="
        robotnik_base_control
        joint_read_state_controller
       ">
      </node>
    </group>


  </group>


  <node pkg="twist_mux" type="twist_mux" name="twist_mux">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find summit_xl_control)/config/twist_mux.yaml" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel_out" to="$(arg cmd_vel)" />
  </node>
  <node pkg="twist_mux" type="twist_marker" name="twist_marker">
    <remap from="twist"  to="$(arg cmd_vel)"/>
    <remap from="marker" to="twist_marker"/>
  </node>


</launch>
```

How do I fix the launch file so that I can launch the robot model in gazebo?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the `summit_xl` package. You're getting the error because [summit_xl_one_robot.launch](https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/summit_xl_sim/blob/c6852dc9ee3ad7f5daab52b15adb85b91dea4666/summit_xl_gazebo/launch/summit_xl_one_robot.launch#L102) passes on args for both `arm_model` and `arm_manufacturer`. The error you're seeing is because neither of the args are actually used in `summit_xl_complete.launch`. It's possible the author meant for those to be params, but I'm not sure.

To fix the problem you'll need to remove these two lines in `simmut_xl_one_robot.launch` shown in the link above:

```
<arg name="arm_manufacturer" value="$(arg arm_manufacturer)"/>
<arg name="arm_model" value="$(arg arm_model)"/>
```

Comment: I solved the error by actually adding those lines into the .xacro file as when searching the file there were not any statements that matched the ones listed in the error message.